# unable to validate checkbox with []

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

ok the following code works fine if i put the checkbox room field without [] but if i do like this

```
$(function() {

// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#reservation").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        room[]: "required",
        start: "required",
        end: "required",
        name: "required",
        phone: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        address: "required"
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        room[]: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Select one room",
        start: "Select Check In date in Room Availability",
        end: "Select Check Out date in Room Availability",
        name: "Enter your full name",
        phone: "Phone number is required",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        address: "Address is required"
    },


    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

});

then the room field with room[] is not throwing any error to select one room.

Comment: It is throwing an error. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Comment: By using valid syntax for the object literal. See the various answers on the duplicate question.

Comment: there is only one topic u posted a link to and im unable to find th answer to that post bro. im new to stackoverflow

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html

Update with working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaGbeP

```
$(function() {
$('#myform').validate({
rules: {
  "room[]": {
    required: true
  }
},
messages: {
  "room[]": {
    required: "Please select a room<br/>"
  }
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  if (element.is(":radio")) {
    error.appendTo(element.parents('.container'));
  } else { // This is the default behavior 
    error.insertAfter(element);
  }
}
});

});

<form id="myform">
  <label for='room'>Select one room:</label>
  <p class='container'>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='room[]' value='room one' />one</label>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='room[]' value='room two' />two</label>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='room[]' value='room three' />three</label>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: but i have multiple values to my checkbox

Comment: The OP is dealing with checkboxes, not radio buttons. PHP depends on having `[]` in the name in order to accept multiple values for a single name. Removing the `[]` will break things.

Comment: @Stuart the fields are checkbox as user gets option to select multiple options so it is required to have the input field as checkbox so the name should be like name="room[]"

Comment: We are talking about jquery validation here, not the php side of things! I said to remove the [] from the validation rules as you can see above, I've edited the HTML for clarity... Apologies for not showing them in the initial code paste.

Comment: yes @Stuart its jquery validation thought i know i am using it for php but i needed it to validate checkbox  with name="room[]"

Comment: Apologies, I think I'm going crazy... on checkboxes, you can add the [] but make sure to quote it, updated code above

Comment: i tried this but its not throwing any error message

 `
        rules: {
      room: {
        required: true
     }
   start: "required",
   end: "required",
            name: "required",
            phone: "required",
   email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
   address: "required"
        },
        
       `

Comment: @Stuart it works greate thanks soo much :)

Comment: Glad to be if help - got there in the end. Thanks for marking as accepted answer even after someone else down voted :)